# create an 'action' drop down box to decide order of table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, drop-down-menu

I have an index page which has a table in it. I'd like a drop down box that will display various ways to order the table. like this:

```
 '<%= f.select :order_by [service_date, Car_name, etc.]'
```

I'm not sure what to put in my controller to be able to read the value in the drop box and then submit the new order

```
#index_controller
def index
  @cars = Car.find(:all, :order => 'value of drop down box in here')
  @cars_available = Car.where(:available => true, :booked => false)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @cars}
  end
end
```

any ideas?

Comment: `index` uses the GET method.  All forms use POST by default, so unless there's some *RoR magic* there to help you out, you may need to set this option explicitly on your `form_for` blocks, otherwise the target route will not recognized by rails.

Comment: @freemasonjson could i use a before_filter in the controller to collect the default value? or am i being stupid

Comment: you could if you need to do something to it for more than one of your controller actions.  As in `before_filter` is useful to centralize code that would otherwise be duplicated over multiple actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works like any other **form parameter**:

```
# GET
def index
  @cars = Car.find(:all, :order => params[:car][:order_by])
  @cars_available = Car.where(:available => true, :booked => false)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @cars}
  end
end
```

You should define an instance method `order_by` in your `Car` model to return a default value:

```
def order_by
  "your default order_by" #will determine the default selected order_by on a form
end
```

**PS** You need this method, or atleast `attr_reader :order_by` or `attr_accessor :order_by`, or else you will get an Execption for `f.select :order_by`

Comment: thanks for the help, i have set up the code but im getting a NoMethodError, undifined method [] in the controller. i have done the default value. i think it isnt picking up the contents of the select before it rendors

Comment: right, for the default value, I believe you have to specify it in the options hash like `:selected => @car.order_by`.  Maybe it only works with `input[type='text']`.  As for the `NoMethodError`, can you print out `params` for me to take a look?

Comment: thanks for your help and advice. got it to work eventually. just took a bit of playing. your original answer worked i just forgot the attr_accessor